# I found a useful Ethereum script. How do I run it ELI5?

Tags: dapps, contract-invocation, usability

What's the least painful option to use the [Stackexchange Bounty script described here](http://blog.ether.camp/post/145202667083/ethereum-studio-integrates-oraclize)?

I'm dreaming of a chrome extension :)

Comment: See on reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4lvevy/i_found_a_useful_ethereum_script_how_do_i_run_it/

Comment: For those not familiar with the acronym, "ELI5" means "explain (it) like I'm 5 (years old)"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "least painful" option would be to sign-up for an Ethereum Studio account and follow the (very comprehensive) "How to run the application in Ethereum Studio" section of the [README file](https://github.com/ether-camp/dapp-stackexchange-bounty/blob/master/README.md) in the GitHub repository.

Transposing the instructions to a different IDE would be possible, but unless you know what you're doing this would involve some degree of pain, and therefore wouldn't be "least painful".

Creating a Chrome plug-in is another project in itself.